# "Fixed amount discount for whole cart" not working

Tags: discount, promotions

I would like to set a simple rule:
If two specific items are found in the cart, apply the fixed amount discount for the whole cart. 
I have been trying to set this up with SKUs:

*If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:*

*SKU is XY*

*SKU is XX*

Action:    *Apply - Fixed amount discount for whole cart*

*Discount amount: 100*

I've tried setting Stop Further Rule Processing to No and Yes and it has no impact.

It works perfectly if  there is only one product in conditions, but if I set two, there is no discount at all.

I'm on Magento Enterprise 1.14.1.

Can anyone advise how to set this to make it work? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding 2 separate conditions:

If an item is FOUND in the cart with ALL of these conditions true:

SKU is XY

If an item is FOUND in the cart with ALL of these conditions true:

SKU is XX

Action: Apply - Fixed amount discount for whole cart